# scala type bounds and variance

Tags: scala, generics, types, typeclass

Please explain what princeples of scala typing and why should be use here

I got type hierarchy

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends A
cladd D extends C
```

And other type class

```
class Hub(init) {
 def add(elem): Hub = new Hub(elem)
}
```

I need to do edit typing of `Hub` and `Hub.add` that it should work like this

```
val a : Hub[D] = Hub(new D)
val b : Hub[A] = a.add(new B)
val c : Hub[A] = b.add(new C)
val d : Hub[A] = c.add(new D)
```

And this should be compile error

```
val e : Hub[C] = b.add(new C)
```

how should I edit it and why?

P.S. This is not valid scala code, it is for sake of types example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `add` parametric with proper type bounds `[B >: A]` (see like half the standard library collections' methods for typical examples).

```
class Hub[A](a: A) {
 def add[B >: A](b: B): Hub[B] = new Hub[B](b)
}
object Hub {
  def apply[A](a: A): Hub[A] = new Hub[A](a)
}

val a : Hub[D] = Hub(new D)
val b : Hub[A] = a.add(new B)
val c : Hub[A] = b.add(new C)
val d : Hub[A] = c.add(new D)
// val e : Hub[C] = b.add(new C) type mismatch
```

In `[B >: A](b: B)` compiler tries to infer `B` s that it would both:

- be a supertype of `A`
- be a supertype of a passed value so that it could be upcasted to it

Comment: Thanks, I guess I understand my mistake. I though that if we got `add[P >: Q](elem: P)` and we have `a = Hub[A]`, we could not pass `a.add(new D)`, because D is subptype of A and we got [P >: Q], instead that means that we could pass subtype, but it will be inference to supertype. am I right?

Comment: Well, basically compiler will find such value of B that elem can be upcasted to it and A values could be upcasted to it. And compiler will try to find the most specific type that match these requirements (least upper bound - LUB) as Any would always works and would almost never be what we need.